# How to package a kivy python windows

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I've been trying to package a kivy app for windows with PyInstaller but I have could not do it. My app is split into a few modules.
Here is my tree directory:

[image]

The main.py file calls the mainframe that contains my kivy app.

```
import os, sys
from kivy.resources import resource_add_path
from controllers.corecontroller import CoreController
from views.app import PassEwokApp

workspace=os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

if __name__=="__main__":
    resource_add_path(os.path.join(workspace,"resources"))
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        resource_add_path(os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS))
    app=PassEwokApp()
    controller=CoreController(app)
    controller.start()
```

Then main.py file is the file which I run the PyInstaller.
The command would be: `python -m PyInstaller main.py --onefile`.
The result of that is a .exe file of 426mb (which is ridiculous) and this one doesn't make anything, no screen appears. I thought that problem was because I was loading kv files with  `Builder.load_file("bla_bla.kv")` so I changed that for loading kv files like strings.
For example in views\app.py which is the mainframe.

[image]

I load the kv file like this.

```
import os
kv_file=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"views\\app.kv")
with open(kv_file,"r") as kv:
    css=kv.read()
Builder.load_string(css)
```

and so in the rest of the files where I need it.
Then I run the pyinstaller again and I had a .exe file of 426 mb and again it doesn't make anything but after a long time (almost 5 minutes) appears a window with errors about it doesn't find my modules `controllers, models, utilities, and views` and other kivy modules.

So, how I can do it correctly? Why the final .exe file is too large?

**Edit 1**

I change the .spec file and added the submodules which it doesn't had recognizing and finally my app appears, but it takes too long for show the windows, almost 5 minutes, so i checked the process runing in my pc
and i saw that the process of Antimalware runing strong with the process of my app, i don't know if it has something to do with that take too long in appear.

[image]

My .spec file

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_submodules
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

submodules = collect_submodules('controllers')
submodules += collect_submodules('models')
submodules += collect_submodules('views')
submodules += collect_submodules('utilities')
submodules += collect_submodules('pycryptodome')
submodules += collect_submodules('kivy')
from kivy.tools.packaging.pyinstaller_hooks import hookspath, runtime_hooks

a = Analysis(['D:\\Python\\kivy\\passwordmanager\\main.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\Python\\kivy\\passwordmanager'],
             binaries=[],
                         datas=[],
             hiddenimports=submodules,
             hookspath=hookspath(),
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=runtime_hooks(),
             excludes=[],
                         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,Tree('D:\\Python\\kivy\\passwordmanager'),
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas, 
                    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          [],
          name='Passewok',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None , icon='resources\\app-200x200.ico')
```